# Matlab: how to work with different outputs of function

Tags: matlab, function, output

I've got the function

```
function [imag2] = sumIntegral(x,w,a,b,c,p)
    imag2 = zeros(p-1,p);
for k = 1:p-1
    f = @(t)(1:p-1==k)*Integrand[1](t,x,w,a,b,c);
    imag2(k,:) = quadv(f,x(k),x(k+1));
end
```

whereas 
`Integrand[1]` should be `real2` of this function

`[real2,real3,imag2,imag3] = Integrand(t,x,w,a,b,c,p);`

The problem is, if I define the `Integrand` function before, I get an error, as `t` is undefined. Do you know how to write `real2` as a function in `t`?

Comment: would you mind to better specify your question and to put in a clearer way? thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for your quick answers so far. What I wanted to know is how to get access to real2 as a function in t. I want to declare [real2,real3,imag2,imag3] = Integrand(t,x,w,a,b,c,p);
first and then write f = @(t)(1:p-1==k)*real2, but I always get the error, that t is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a dummy proxy function that only outputs the first argument:

```
function real2 = MyIntergrand(t,x,w,a,b,c)
    real2 = Integrand(t,x,w,a,b,c);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define your quick function **out of the for loop**

```
function [imag2] = sumIntegral(x,w,a,b,c,p)
    imag2 = zeros(p-1,p);
    f = @(t)(1:p-1==k)*Integrand[1](t,x,w,a,b,c);
    for k = 1:p-1        
    imag2(k,:) = quadv(f,x(k),x(k+1));
    end
end
```